# bash count files and directory, summary size and EXCLUDE folders that are fuse|sshfs

Tags: bash, shell, find, sshfs, fuse

I need help for a bash script that counts files and folders in a specified directory on a Linux system (Debian), but I want to exclude a specified folder.

I have a main directory named `workdir` with different script files and folders. Inside `workdir`, I have a directory named `mysshfs`. I use fuse/sshfs to mount an external folder in the `mysshfs` folder.

Now I start some commands to get information about file/directory count and file/directory size, but I want to exclude the directoy `mysshfs`.

My bash commands that work:

1. get the full size of `workdir` | **no fuse/sshfs in use**

   ```
   $ du -hs workdir
   ```
2. get the full size of `workdir`, excluding `mysshfs` | **fuse/sshfs in use**

   ```
   $ du -hs --exclude=mysshf workdir
   ```
3. count files in `workdir` | **no fuse/sshfs in use**

   ```
   $ find workdir -type f | wc -l
   ```
4. count folders in `workdir` | **no fuse/sshfs in use**

   ```
   $ find workdir -type d | wc -l
   ```
5. count files in `workdir`, excluding `mysshfs` | **no fuse/sshfs in use**

   ```
   $ find workdir -type f -not -path "*mysshfs*" | wc -l
   ```
6. count folders in `workdir`, excluding `mysshfs` | **no fuse/sshfs in use**

   ```
   $ find workdir -type d -not -path "*mysshfs*" | wc -l
   ```

When I use commands **5 & 6** and the remote directory is mounted under the `mysshfs` directory, the commands hang.

The commands eventually works and show the correct output, but it looks like the commands are still looking inside the excluded directory even though they shouldn't be, so it takes a long time to display the result.

Where is my error or did I forget something in my commands 5 & 6? Or can I use other commands for my results?

I need to count files and directories using 2 separate commands
and exclude a specified folder that is mounted over fuse/sshfs to get a fast result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-prune` to avoid descending into subdirectories. Try these commands instead:

```
find workdir -path "*/mysshfs/*" -prune -o \( -type f -print \) | wc -l
find workdir -path "*/mysshfs/*" -prune \( -type d -print \)  | wc -l
```

Comment: `-name mysshfs` would make more sense and be more reliable than `-path "*/mysshfs/*"`. I think you're missing a `-o` in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

To skip files on `fuse.sshfs` FS types, use:

```
find workdir//. -fstype fuse.sshfs -prune -o -type f -print | grep -c //
```

Or use `-xdev` to not traverse to any other file system (of any type).

In any case, you can't use `wc -l` to count files as the newline character is as valid as any in a file type. Here we count the number of occurrences of `//` which is guaranteed to occur only once, though with GNU `find`, you could also do:

```
find workdir -fstype fuse.sshfs -prune -o -type f -printf . | wc -c
```

Or to get a break down of number of files per type (`f` for *regular*, `d` for directory, `l` for symlink, `p` for named pipe, etc):

```
find workdir -fstype fuse.sshfs -prune -o -type f -printf '%y\n' |
  sort |
  uniq -c
```